# Can't find "wincontypes"

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to use the COORD struct of the crate winapi.

btw: I'm pretty new to rust, so I might have missed something obvious.

My code looks like this.

```
extern crate kernel32;
extern crate winapi;
extern crate libc;

use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use winapi::um::wincontypes;

...
```

The last line shows this error:

```
unresolved import `winapi::um::wincontypes`

no `wincontypes` in `um`rustc(E0432)
main.rs(7, 5): no `wincontypes` in `um`
```

I looked at the documentation(https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.7/winapi/um/wincontypes/struct.COORD.html) and it is there, so I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of winapi? `wincontypes` was added in version 0.3.7, released last april, so if you have an older version it won't be there. You can check which version you have in your `Cargo.lock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the one hand, it has something to do with the RUST version. Now the latest version is 0.3.7.

Use `cargo --version` to check

If not the latest version, please use `rustup update` to update

On the other hand, you did not add dependencies.

[How to add dependencies?](https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started)

And you can refer this [article](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs) to learn more.

Why no `wincontypes` in `um` rustc(E0432)?

**Modify dependencies in the Cargo. toml manifest file.**

Like this:

```
[dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3", features = ["winuser","wincontypes"] }
```